# Can't call method without package or object reference

Tags: perl

I'm working on learning Perl and I'm running through the documentation at [Perl.org](http://www.perl.org/books/beginning-perl/)

I've got the below code from the tutorial and it's throwing the error:

```
Can't call method "forename" without a package or object reference.
```

Package code (person7.pm):

```
package Person;
#Class for storing data about a person
#person7.pm
use warnings;
use strict;
use Carp;

my @Everyone = 0;

sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my $self  = {@_};

    bless( $self, $class );
    push @Everyone, $self;
    return $self;
}

#Object accessor methods
sub address    { $_[0]->{address}    = $_[1] if defined $_[1]; $_[0]->{address} }
sub surname    { $_[0]->{surname}    = $_[1] if defined $_[1]; $_[0]->{surname} }
sub forename   { $_[0]->{forename}   = $_[1] if defined $_[1]; $_[0]->{forename} }
sub phone_no   { $_[0]->{phone_no}   = $_[1] if defined $_[1]; $_[0]->{phone_no} }
sub occupation { $_[0]->{occupation} = $_[1] if defined $_[1]; $_[0]->{occupation} }

#Class accessor methods
sub headcount { scalar @Everyone }
sub everyone  {@Everyone}

1;
```

Calling code (classatr2.plx):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# classatr2.plx
use warnings;
use strict;
use Person7;

print "In the beginning: ", Person->headcount, "\n";

my $object = Person->new(
    surname    => "Galilei",
    forename   => "Galileo",
    address    => "9.81 Pisa Apts.",
    occupation => "bombadier"
);
print "Population now: ", Person->headcount, "\n";

my $object2 = Person->new(
    surname    => "Einstein",
    forename   => "Albert",
    address    => "9E16, Relativity Drive",
    occupation => "Plumber"
);
print "Population now: ", Person->headcount, "\n";

print "\nPeople we know:\n";
for my $person ( Person->everyone ) {
    print $person->forename, " ", $person->surname, "\n";
}
```

I cannot see why it is throwing an error.  I'm using Perl 5, version 16 on Windows. Both files are in the same directory.

Comment: person7.pm file is located in the same directory as the calling code.  The package name is Person.

Comment: That's correct. Based on the tutorial I'm following, the package name is Person, but the file name is Person7.pm and the tutorial has the use statement as Person7.  If I state "use Person" instead of "use Person7" it can't find the pm file.

Comment: Have you checked what `everyone` returns, and is it what you think it is?

Comment: @Everyone wasn't returning what I was expecting.  Thanks

Comment: When in doubt, `use Data::Dumper; print Dumper( $data_structure );` will help find the problem!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first element in the Everyone array is zero:

```
@Everyone = 0;
```

You can't call a method on a zero:

```
0->forename
```

To initialize an empty array, use just

```
my @Everyone;
```

Comment: That was it.  I completely overlooked the assignment.  Thanks for the assist.

Comment: I had this error connected when I called a routine from a package, which had some routines without a sub keyword defined, which might have invalidated the package (or perhaps missing a return value 1 at the end of the package too).